# reshape dictionary of key values where values are pandas Data-Frames

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I have a huge dictionary, where each key points to a single pandas dataframe.
How can I get all values, flatten, then reshape them to get a one pandas dataframe ?

the following doesn't work, but gives a hint on where I'm stucking

```
np.array(list(map(dictionary.values(), pd.values)).flatten()
```

pandas has no class imethod as values().

Comment: would you like show us your input and output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
len(np.array([np.array(dictionary[idx].values).flatten() for idx in dictionary]).flatten())
```

Simple list comprehention, poor, I am.

Comment: Try `df = pd.concat(dictionary)` instead

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `pd.concat` can work , since you have dict format as key : dataframe , in `pd.concat` , it will turn on the para [keys](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), so it will adding additional level(value of `keys` in `dict` ) when combine you dict's value .

---

For example

```
yourdict={'A':df,'B':df,'C':df}
pd.concat(yourdict)
     0
A 0  1
  1  2
  2  3
  3  4
  4  5
  5  6
B 0  1
  1  2
  2  3
  3  4
  4  5
  5  6
C 0  1
  1  2
  2  3
  3  4
  4  5
  5  6
pd.concat(yourdict).values
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6]], dtype=int64)
```